# Why does my code show traceback even when I catch the exception?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

This piece of code is behaving really weird. I've essentially copied a format of `try`/`except` block I've used in another code, since it worked fine on the other one. In this one, however, I'm getting both the traceback *and* the exception message, which I can't really explain.

```
    def input_rows_columns():
        try:
            print("How many rows do you want?")
            rows = int(input("Rows: "))
            print("How many columns do you want?")
            columns = int(input("Columns: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease insert numbers here\n")

        if rows <= 0 or columns <= 0:
            raise ValueError("\nPlease use numbers greater than zero here\n")

        return rows, columns


    def main():
        print("This program will make a barn for you")

        rows, columns = input_rows_columns()

        print(rows)
        print(columns)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

[Here is an image of the traceback when you input zero:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0b3x.png)

[Here is an image of the traceback when you input a string:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7P68.png)

Sorry if there was a better way to put the traceback, this was the best I could figure out

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the first program (the one I copied the format from) had another `try`/`except` when he called the function out in `main()`:

```
    def main():
        print("This program will calculate the volume of a rectangular box given \
            its lenght, width, and height.\n")

        success = False
        try:
            # get_dimensions() has similar structure as the input_rows_columns() from the program above
            lenght, width, height = get_dimensions('Length', 'Width', 'Height')
            success = True
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nGoodbye.")

        # success = True ficou implícito
        if success:
            volume = lenght * width * height
            print("\nThe volume of the box is %.2f." % volume)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

However, when I introduce this concept to the upper program it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: For the first screenshot , you're raising your own ValueError and not catching it. For the second one, you never set `rows` because an error is thrown, so you would need to set that in your `except` block.

Comment: Please din't post images of code/data - just copy and paste the Traceback and format it as code.

Comment: Sorry for posting an image of the traceback, I just don't know how to capture in text, next time I'll do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all related to where an error is caught vs thrown(raised).

If you don't `raise` the ValueError you caught, the code continues down a path where rows is not actually defined.

Where you have:

`int(input("Rows: "))`

...This code executes before `rows` gets assigned, so if this throws a `ValueError`, which bubbles up to your `except ValueError` line. Now you are in a state where `rows` is not assigned.

If you want to stop the program once this error gets hit, you can simply `raise` or call `sys.exit()`

```
except ValueError:
    print("\nPlease insert numbers here\n")
    raise
```